# Armadillo/MKL/Other ? interpolation in C++ equivalent to Scipy interpolate

Tags: python, c++, scipy, interpolation, intel-mkl

I would like to find a robust/established library preferably one of Armadillo/MKL which has got an interpolation method doing the same as the interpolation `intep1d` in `interpolate` library of `scipy` with type `linear` (default).

Info about the Scipy one is here http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html#scipy.interpolate.interp1d

I do not find identical method in MKL so far.
What did you use for C++ multidim linear interpolation ?

---

If no equivalent do exist, I need to understand the interp1d better...

First `interp1d` computes a funtion`f` from `x` and `y` such that `f(x) = y` (curve fitting),

From the Scipy doc

> x and y are arrays of values used to approximate some function f: y =
>   f(x). This class returns a function whose call method uses
>   interpolation to find the value of new points.

How is this function `f` computed from `x` and `y` ? is it regular linear curve fitting ? is there a method for this in MKL/Armadillo ?

Comment: See if the first section at http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html helps to explain `interp1d`.  (If you haven't already, also take a look at the docstring (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html) and its description of the `kind` arugment, and try the example that it contains.)

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser means that it interpolates linearly between two data points in the x,y dataset ? could you confirm ?

Comment: Sorry, the second link in my previous comment was meant to be http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html.  And yes (as you can see in the docstring), the default `kind` of interpolation is linear.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser I mean: could you confirm that what is meant by linear interpolation (the default one) is the basic common sense linear interpolation (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation) between two consecutive points in the dataset ?

Comment: Yes, `interp1d` with the default `kind="linear"` implements the standard definition of linear interpolation:  the interpolating function is a straight line between consecutive pairs of points.

Answer (score 1):

As of Armadillo 5.200+, there is a function for 1D interpolation: [interp1()](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#interp1)